# Custom tableview cells similar to this

Tags: ios, uitableview

What is the best way to achieve this style in uitableview cells?

[image: TableView]

I need to know how to achieve that result. I've seen tutorials but nothing similar. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You would also need a very big iPhone to get that exact look =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this by creating a custom cell add shadows on UILabel's text and custom UISwitch. See apple's elements sample for faster performance they are using drawRect for drawing cell. Also you will find on google about gradient cell using drawRect. That should help you to achieve the result you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

The round up and grouping is part of the `UITableView` style gruped:

```
- (id)initWithFrame:myCGRect style:UITableViewStyleGrouped
```

The color is part of `UITableViewCell` background color, for the switches you would have to create those images and then add them as a subview of your `UISwitch` using:

> //This method is inherited by UISwitch from UIView

```
[mySwitch addSubview:yourCustomView]
```

Comment: I think he is using something more than the background color property... And what about the black border of the table? And that separator style?